# how to send the headers and consume the same headers in consumer using Kafka (node-rdkafka)

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I try to implement a retry mechanism for my Kafka topic. so I set rerty count in producer headers. while consuming the consumer doesn't give me the headers.

```
var headers = [ {"retry":5}]
producer.produce(topic, partition, message, key, timestamp,headers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in producer, I misplaced header argument

instead of this

```
var headers = [ {"retry":5}]
producer.produce(topic, partition, message, key, timestamp,headers);
```

it's need to be

```
var headers = [ {"retry":5}]
producer.produce(topic, partition, message, key, timestamp,opaque,headers);
```

headers will be retrun as object. you can read your header in onData function using data.header

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation found here for producer.produce() in the standard api: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rdkafka

"*you can send an opaque token here, which gets passed along to your delivery reports*"

This implies the opaque value is not stored with your message, which is why it's not available from the consumer. Instead, the opaque value is sent back in the delivery report. That means you would have to provide a delivery report callback and read the value from the delivery report.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes, you'll get your headers that way:

```
"headers":[{"env":{"type":"Buffer","data":[105,100,116,51]}},{"deployment.messagingModee":"Buffer","data":[82,83,71,62,82,64,81,71,78,71]}}],"size":37266,"key":null,"topic":"TOPIC_NAME","offset":214rtition":4,"timestamp":1681908958595}
```